# After the reinstall of Ubuntu, Windows don't appear on the grub list boot

Tags: 14.04, dual-boot, grub2, uefi, windows-10

I'm booting with the UEFI mode, Before the reinstall of ubuntu I had got a dual boot working perfectly on UEFI mode. But after doing a mistake on my old ubuntu (deleting some folders/files on the root...) I reinstalled a new ubuntu on the old partition of the old ubuntu.

The problem now Windows don't appear on the grub boot list, so I can't boot on it, but if we take a look on the boot-info generated by boot-repair, windows partitions seems to be there !

Here is a parte of the Boot-info :

```
============================= Boot Info Summary: ===============================

 => No boot loader is installed in the MBR of /dev/sda.

sda1: __________________________________________________________________________

File system:       ntfs
Boot sector type:  Windows 8/2012: NTFS
Boot sector info:  No errors found in the Boot Parameter Block.
Operating System:  
Boot files:        /bootmgr /boot/bcd

sda2: __________________________________________________________________________

File system:       vfat
Boot sector type:  Windows 8/2012: FAT32
Boot sector info:  No errors found in the Boot Parameter Block.
Operating System:  
Boot files:        /EFI/Boot/bootx64.efi /EFI/ubuntu/MokManager.efi 
                   /EFI/ubuntu/fwupx64.efi /EFI/ubuntu/grubx64.efi 
                   /EFI/ubuntu/shimx64.efi 
                   /EFI/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgr.efi 
                   /EFI/Microsoft/Boot/memtest.efi /bootmgr

sda3: __________________________________________________________________________

File system:       ntfs
Boot sector type:  Windows 8/2012: NTFS
Boot sector info:  No errors found in the Boot Parameter Block.
Operating System:  
Boot files:        

sda4: __________________________________________________________________________

File system:       ntfs
Boot sector type:  Windows 8/2012: NTFS
Boot sector info:  No errors found in the Boot Parameter Block.
Operating System:  
Boot files:        /Windows/System32/winload.exe

sda5: __________________________________________________________________________

File system:       ext4
Boot sector type:  -
Boot sector info: 
Operating System:  Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS
Boot files:        /boot/grub/grub.cfg /etc/fstab

sda6: __________________________________________________________________________

File system:       swap
Boot sector type:  -
Boot sector info: 

sda7: __________________________________________________________________________

File system:       ntfs
Boot sector type:  Windows 8/2012: NTFS
Boot sector info:  No errors found in the Boot Parameter Block.
Operating System:  
Boot files:        

sda8: __________________________________________________________________________

File system:       
Boot sector type:  -
Boot sector info: 
Mounting failed:   mount: unknown filesystem type ''

sda9: __________________________________________________________________________

File system:       ext4
Boot sector type:  -
Boot sector info: 
Operating System:  
Boot files:    

============================ Drive/Partition Info: =============================

Drive: sda _____________________________________________________________________
Disk /dev/sda: 119.2 GiB, 128035676160 bytes, 250069680 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt

Partition  Boot  Start Sector    End Sector  # of Sectors  Id System

/dev/sda1                   1   250,069,679   250,069,679  ee GPT


GUID Partition Table detected.

Partition  Attrs   Start Sector    End Sector  # of Sectors System
/dev/sda1      R          2,048     2,099,199     2,097,152 Windows Recovery Environment (Windows)
/dev/sda2             2,099,200     2,303,999       204,800 EFI System partition
/dev/sda3             2,304,000     2,566,143       262,144 EFI System partition
/dev/sda4             2,566,144   149,889,023   147,322,880 Data partition (Windows/Linux)
/dev/sda5           149,889,024   189,889,023    40,000,000 Data partition (Linux)
/dev/sda6           196,952,064   213,575,679    16,623,616 Swap partition (Linux)
/dev/sda7      R    213,575,680   233,292,255    19,716,576 Windows Recovery Environment (Windows)
/dev/sda8      R    233,292,256   250,069,471    16,777,216 Intel Fast Flash (iFFS) partition (for Intel Rapid Start technology)
/dev/sda9           189,890,560   196,952,063     7,061,504 Data partition (Linux)

Attributes: R=Required, N=No Block IO, B=Legacy BIOS Bootable, +=More bits set
```

Can you pleas help me the find fix the windows boot and to add it on the grub list with the actual ubuntu (dual boot) ?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you tried [boot repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair)?

Comment: Running `sudo update-grub` should be enough.